# Adding a video from JavaScript to my html page

Tags: javascript, html

So I am working on my School assignment to create an HTML page to play a video from links provided in an array.
I am trying to add a video to my HTML page from an array of links in JavaScript. But my video is just showing an image and isn't playing like a video so far with the code I created. I am not sure about the mistake I am making. Can someone please help me out?

```js
// Data for the "HTML Video" Page

var video = {
    controls: true, 
    width: 320,
    height: 240,
    source: [
        {src: "https://github.com/allanrandall/BTI225W17/raw/master/movie.mp4", type: "video/mp4"},
        {src: "https://github.com/allanrandall/BTI225W17/raw/master/movie.ogg", type: "video/ogg"},
        {src: "https://github.com/allanrandall/BTI225W17/raw/master/movie.webm", type: "video/webm"}
    ]
};


window.onload = function () {

    var VideoPlayer = document.querySelector('#video');
    var string = "";
    string += "<figure>";
    string += "<video width=" + video.width + "height=" + video.height + "controls>";
    for (var i = 0; i < video.source.length; i++)
    {
        string += "<source src=" + video.source[i].src + " type=" + video.source[i].type + " />";
    }
    string += "</video>";
    string += "</figure>";
    VideoPlayer.innerHTML += string;

};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>BTI225</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lab3-theme.css" />
    <script src="js/video.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <div class="center">
            <h2>
                BTI225 - Assignment 3
            </h2>
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <div class="center">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="list.html">List</a></li>
                <li><a href="table.html">Table</a></li>
                <li><a href="image.html">Image</a></li>
                <li><a href="audio.html">Audio</a></li>
                <li><a href="video.html">Video</a></li>
                <li><a href="seneca.html">Seneca</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <section class="main center">

        <!-- Start your code here -->
        <h2>HTML5 Video</h2>
        <div id ="video"></div>
        <!-- End your code here  -->

    </section>
    <footer>
        <div class="center">
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add **double quote** for the attributes of `<video>`.

You can use single quote to wrap your string like below.

Or you can use reverse slash to escape the double quote like `"\""`.

```js
// Data for the "HTML Video" Page

var video = {
    controls: true, 
    width: 320,
    height: 240,
    source: [
        {src: "https://github.com/allanrandall/BTI225W17/raw/master/movie.mp4", type: "video/mp4"},
        {src: "https://github.com/allanrandall/BTI225W17/raw/master/movie.ogg", type: "video/ogg"},
        {src: "https://github.com/allanrandall/BTI225W17/raw/master/movie.webm", type: "video/webm"}
    ]
};


window.onload = function () {

    var VideoPlayer = document.querySelector('#video');
    var string = "";
    string += "<figure>";
    //use single quote to wrap the string
    //the output for your origial method
    console.log("<video width=" + video.width + "height=" + video.height + "controls>")
    //Working by using single quote
    console.log('<video width="' + video.width + '" height="' + video.height + '" controls>')
    //Working by using reverse slash.
    console.log("<video width=\"" + video.width + "\" height=\"" + video.height + "\" controls>")
    string += '<video width="' + video.width + '" height="' + video.height + '" controls>';
    for (var i = 0; i < video.source.length; i++)
    {
        string += '<source src="' + video.source[i].src + '" type="' + video.source[i].type + '" />';
    }
    string += "</video>";
    string += "</figure>";
    VideoPlayer.innerHTML += string;

};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>BTI225</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lab3-theme.css" />
    <script src="js/video.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <div class="center">
            <h2>
                BTI225 - Assignment 3
            </h2>
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <div class="center">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="list.html">List</a></li>
                <li><a href="table.html">Table</a></li>
                <li><a href="image.html">Image</a></li>
                <li><a href="audio.html">Audio</a></li>
                <li><a href="video.html">Video</a></li>
                <li><a href="seneca.html">Seneca</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <section class="main center">

        <!-- Start your code here -->
        <h2>HTML5 Video</h2>
        <div id ="video"></div>
        <!-- End your code here  -->

    </section>
    <footer>
        <div class="center">
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A **space** before `height` and a **space** before `controls` in the following line:

`string += "<video width=" + video.width + " height=" + video.height + " controls>";`

is missing.

```js
// Data for the "HTML Video" Page

var video = {
  controls: true,
  width: 320,
  height: 240,
  source: [{
      src: "https://github.com/allanrandall/BTI225W17/raw/master/movie.mp4",
      type: "video/mp4"
    },
    {
      src: "https://github.com/allanrandall/BTI225W17/raw/master/movie.ogg",
      type: "video/ogg"
    },
    {
      src: "https://github.com/allanrandall/BTI225W17/raw/master/movie.webm",
      type: "video/webm"
    }
  ]
};


window.onload = function() {

  var VideoPlayer = document.querySelector('#video');
  var string = "";
  string += "<figure>";
  string += "<video width=" + video.width + " height=" + video.height + " controls>";
  for (var i = 0; i < video.source.length; i++) {
    string += "<source src=" + video.source[i].src + " type=" + video.source[i].type + " />";
  }
  string += "</video>";
  string += "</figure>";
  VideoPlayer.innerHTML += string;

};
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="center">
    <h2>
      BTI225 - Assignment 3
    </h2>
  </div>
</header>
<nav>
  <div class="center">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="list.html">List</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="table.html">Table</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="image.html">Image</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="audio.html">Audio</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="video.html">Video</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="seneca.html">Seneca</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<section class="main center">

  <!-- Start your code here -->
  <h2>HTML5 Video</h2>
  <div id="video"></div>
  <!-- End your code here  -->

</section>
<footer>
  <div class="center">
  </div>
</footer>
```